# How to list the outer-most fields of a large document usign PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, data-mining, text-mining

I am just having difficulties to understand this, how can I list outer-most fields when I am working with a huge text datasets? I am trying to implement it in Mongodb and pymongo? any suggestions?

Comment: can you give an example with some sample data, and expected output?

Comment: So I actually have some covid-19 data in Json file. Which I imported via pymongo, seems the data is bulk so when I do "insert_many" and "insert_one" in a if statement it gives me some error but it shows the output, which has "-id", and there 8/9 attributes available. So I was trying to list it's outermost field but didn't able to do that. So I was wondering if there's any suggestions for that.

Comment: Its something like that, any idea how I can list it based on its outer field{"_id":"868998797","id":"8567474","infons":{},"passages":[{"infons":{"license":"This article(https://abc)","name_1":"surname: xyz;given-names:abc","section_type":"TITLE","article-id_pmid":"33647988","name_0":"surname:xyss;given-names:aaa","year":"2000","article-id_pmc":"353543","article-id_publisher-id":"aba32","kwd":"COVID-19 SARS-CoV-2 C"...

Comment: update the question if you can :) add all the extra details, add JSON in code blocks so we can read it.

Comment: Can not share the picture here, but the key attributes are: "_id", "id", "info", "pass", "pid", "pcid", "jrn", "yr", "aut".....These are the attributes available, and the query I am trying to do in Pymongo is: "List the outer-most fields of the documents corpus"; I am not sure whats that outer-most field that I need to list using python, any helps regarding this, not sure how to do it on python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you need, but maybe the bellow can help.

Query

- this query returns an array with all the names of the outer fields
- objectToArray to convert ROOT document to array
- get the first member that is the field name

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49dc)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
    {"_id": 0,
      "outer-fields": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": 
          {"$map": 
            {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"},
              "in": ["$$m.k", "$$m.v"],
              "as": "m"}},
          "in": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$$this", 0]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help, I will try to work on it then. Another thing, I was thinking to consider the last atribute as the outer most field, as it's an areay and have some other nested loops inside, so I might need to print them all to see, or in pymongo there's a east way to do that, trying to figure it out now.

Comment: if you can create a new question, with that nested arrays, post your sample data and the expected output, so people can write a query to get those nested values.